# input type = file in telegram web app doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, telegram, telegram-bot

"input type = file" doesn't work in the built in browser in telegram.

```
<input type ="file" name='image' accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .png" onChange={handleFileChange}/>
```

If there is a way to upload a file via web app from the user's device ?

Comment: ```input type = file``` is not the same as [InputFile](https://core.telegram.org/type/InputFile)

Comment: it's working of other web app ?

Answer (score -1):

User can upload file from any device.
I don't know why standard HTML input tag doesn't render but if you use react use Ant Design input [here is example](https://ant.design/components/input)
Update your telegram app, it can solve a your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).